# R missing values be treated like other values in calculations of counts as a row

Tags: r, stata

```
aaa<-data.frame(x=c(1,3,1,1,2),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

out <- matrix(NA,ncol =2,nrow =3)
for(i in 1:length(unique(aaa$x))) {
  out[i,1]<-unique(aaa$x)[i]
  out[i,2]<-sum(aaa$x==unique(aaa$x)[i])
}
out
         [,1] [,2]
   [1,]    1    3
   [2,]    3    1
   [3,]    2    1
```

How to modify the code and the results were

```
         [,1] [,2]
   [1,]    1    3
   [2,]    2    1
   [3,]    3    1
```

if

```
aaa<-data.frame(x=c(1,NA,1,1,2),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

the results were

```
         [,1] [,2]
   [1,]    1    3
   [2,]    2    1
   [3,]    NA   1
```

In Stata "`tab var1,missing`" would be an answer. In R, I want to use loop to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just counting number of occurrences of each observation, you can use a simple `table` for that.

```
table(aaa$x, useNA="ifany")
```

or to format it more like your output.

```
as.matrix(as.data.frame(table(aaa$x, useNA="ifany")))
#   Var1 Freq
# 1    1    3
# 2    2    1
# 3 <NA>    1
```

No loop needed.

Comment: Thanks. I know table method,but I need a for loop method.

Comment: @stata Why on earth would anyone **need** a for-loop method? This is R after all.

Comment: Because my function use a for-loop method.Thnank you!

Comment: You need to ask your real question explaining what your function is trying to do. It's often not a good idea to seek close translations software to software whenever each has idiomatic ways to do things.

Comment: @Cox The question may have many answers. Only one of answers would be suitable to me，but this one may be not simple one. Why this question is not real question?

Comment: You really need to specify why you want a loop method as nothing in your question requires a loop. 

As MrFlick points out? Why? Hence, the presented method without a loop. As Nick Cox points out, you give no reason why you want a loop and seemingly reject the simple answer. This would be likely why you have been down voted.